# ¿cómo borro registros automaticamente despues de un año de mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, xampp

he diseñado un pequeño sistema que almacena demasiados archivos, pero solo quiero que se almacenen durante un año, es decir, que si el registro ya tiene más de un año, automáticamente se elimine, la base de datos esta echa en mysql y todo lo demás en php. algún ejemplo que me ayuden por favor...

Comment: Podes averiguar sobre como hacer un cron que se ejecute automaticamente todos los dias.. o una vez por mes.. o podes hacerlo a mano...

Comment: para hacerlo todos los días a partir de que se cumpla un año como sería?

Comment: Tenes que investigar como hacer cron jobs en php. O directamente en tu base de datos

Comment: listo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que, si lo haces directamente en el servidor MySQL, como te indica @gbianchi, evitas hacerlo en PHP y tener que utilizar un cron. Para ello sólo tienes que definir un evento, con la periodicidad de borrado que estimes, en el que hagas el borrado de la selección de registros que superen el año de antigüedad.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

Recuerda consultar la variable global event_scheduler y activarla, si fuera necesario, para que funcionen los eventos en el servidor:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler';
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

```
CREATE EVENT borrador
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
  DO
  BEGIN
   DELETE FROM tabla WHERE fecha<NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
  END;
```